Issue with Power BI Embedded API and 401 Unauthorized Error
I'm working on integrating Power BI Embedded using the REST API to retrieve the list of dashboards. I'm using client credentials flow with the correct client ID and client secret to obtain an access token.
My app is registered in Azure AD, and I’ve granted Dashboard.Read.All permissions (delegated type). However, despite having a valid token, I'm still receiving a 401 Unauthorized error when trying to access the API endpoint (../v1.0/myorg/dashboards). I’ve ensured the token is included as a Bearer token in the request headers. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or know what could be causing this?

Can you share your error screenshot ?

As client_credential flow comes under Service Principal authentication which not support for accessing myorgs try to generate access token using authorization_code flow. Refer this MsDoc

Can you please confirm whether you added this application in Power BI workspace and granted Contributor or Admin role to it ?

Is this below solution works for you?

Note: Client Credentials flow is not supported for accessing myorg as it is comes under service principal authentication. To get dashboard present in myorg you need generate the token using authorization_code flow.
Initially, I registered Microsoft Entra ID application, added and granted API permission like below:

To get code, I ran below authorization request in browser:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?  
client_id=<client_id>
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query  
&scope=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default
&state=12345



Now, I generated the access token using authorization_code flow with below parameter:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token 
client_id=<app_id>
client_secret = <client_secret>
redirect_uri= https://jwt.ms
code=<code which generated from browser>
scope= https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default
grant_type = authorization_code

Response:

When I use this generated access token to list dashboards from my workspace, I got response like below.
To list dashboards from workspace:
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/dashboards

As I don't have any dashboards in my workspace,  null value with Status 200 OK.
If still issue persist, Ensure to add Entra ID  registered app to Power BI workspace with Admin or Contributor access.
Reference:
Get Dashboards - Power BI REST APIs 
MsDoc-Embed Power BI content with service principal and client secret
